# Windows phone store cannot access

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

For publishing phonegap apps in windows phone store,dashboard is disabled.and there is a message of terms and conditions,when i click the message box nothing happen

browser is not loading anything.Please help me 
[image]

Comment: Do you use IE? Microsoft often makes its websites work best with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Windows store was updated before couple of months and Microsoft often makes its websites work best with IE. So Please check the same with IE.